# "Failed to initialize Monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection" after running Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have a problem, when I want to start developing applications for android, I did everything like in manual [here](http://developer.android.com) but after installing ADT Plugin in Eclipse I am still getting this error :

> [2011-12-29 14:34:56 - ddms] Failed to initialize Monitor Thread:
>   Unable to establish loopback connection

then, if I try to run an application this appear :

> [2011-12-29 14:41:42 - TestApp] ------------------------------
>   [2011-12-29 14:41:42 - TestApp] Android Launch! [2011-12-29 14:41:42 -
>   TestApp] Connection with adb was interrupted. [2011-12-29 14:41:42 -
>   TestApp] 0 attempts have been made to reconnect. [2011-12-29 14:41:42
>   - TestApp] You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.

Comment: I found this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011539/failed-to-initialize-monitor-thread-unable-to-establish-loopback-connection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No need to turn off tredo interface:
simply add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in `eclipse.ini`:

```
 openFile
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple : turn off Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface.

This probably converts IP4 to IPv6 addresses or something, resulting in an IPv6 address for your localhost (strange though, that a PING still results in IP4). Anyway, turning it off (Device manager > View > Show hidden devices > right click on Teredo > disable) solves the problem!

I found out by doing a `ipconfig /all` in the NON working situation. It showed :

> Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:
>
> Connection-specific DNS Suffix . :
>
> Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
>
> Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
>
> DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
>
> Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
>
> IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . :
>   2001:0:5ef5:79fb:####:###:####:####(Preferred)
>
> Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c47:###:####:####
>   (Preferred)