# Failed to initialize monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

Since yesterday suddenly my Eclipse does not work anymore. The error is "Failed to initialize monitor Thread: Unable to establishe loopback connection". I googled and tried the following:

- IPv6 completely off, if I ping localhost I get back 127.0.0.1
- Firewall exceptions added for eclipse.exe and adb.exe
- Adb killed and re-started
- Reset Adb from eclipse
- Virus scanners off (temporarily)

Nothing seems to help, I'm lost. Besides, if I try to update I get the error message also:

Some sites could not be found. See the error log for more detail.
Unable to read repository at http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/content.xml.
Permission denied: connect

.. I can browse from Eclipse (with the Internal Web Browser perspective), so there is an internet connection. Furthermore, no proxies, just a direct connection.

Comment: The weirdest thing just happened.. I logged in to my company network (behind proxy) and the whole thing works again! Without changing anything to Internet Explorer and / or Eclipse configuration. ... So, I guess, somewhere I've told Eclipse to use the proxyserver?! It's NOT in Windows > Preferences > General > Network Connections.

Clue, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution : turn off Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface.

This probably converts IP4 to IPv6 addresses or something, resulting in an IPv6 address for your localhost (strange though, that a PING still results in IP4). Anyway, turning it off (Device manager > View > Show hidden devices > right click on Teredo > disable) solves the problem!

I found out by doing a ipconfig /all in the NON working situation. It showed :

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface

Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0

DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No

Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fb:####:###:####:####(Preferred)

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3c47:###:####:#### (Preferred)

//edit : I guess it's a workaround untill Eclipse supports IPv6

Comment: Comment; I found that Win7 re-enables my Teredo device after each boot. Even when I deinstall. So I made a batchfile (run as Administrator) which issues the following commands :

>netsh interface teredo set state disabled
>"D:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\eclipse.exe"

Answer (score 5):

My solution was: Terminate my proxifier.exe

I guess eclipse doesn't like proxies

Comment: I confirm Eclipse doesn't like proxies! This did it for me, too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11327411/552958

I suspect you are using Java 7 which looks like it prefers IPV6 over IPV4.
So you need to make sure that `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` is a jvm argument.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your anti virus blocked your eclipse,just give allow full access to eclipse on your antivirus security settings.

I faced the same problem in my eclipse and I am using k7 total security.Now the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I came here to add that in my case the solution that worked was to change eclipse.ini.
I did try ALL the other answers in this thread and in other threads (reinstalling Eclipse, reinstalling the Android SDK, reinstalling Java 7 as well, rebooting, checking if Toledo was installed, etc). After an exhaustive google search, I came across this:

http://www.java.net/node/703177

However, I am not knowledgeable enough to understand why it worked. If anyone has any idea, please let me know.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem after updating ADT and SDKs etc.
I did solutions above but didn't work at all.
So, update JDK from "JDK 8u25" to "JDK 8u45" and changed path setting (on Windows and Eclipse). This works for me perfectly!