# Infinispan 8 start up error in domain mode

Tags: infinispan

When ever I start the infinispan server 8 in domain mode, I am getting the below exception .I am not sure what is going wrong.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.datagrid-infinispan-endpoint.memcached.memcached-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.datagrid-infinispan-endpoint.memcached.memcached-connector: DGENDPT10004: Failed to start MemcachedServer
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop 
... 5 more 
Caused by: io.netty.channel.ChannelException: failed to open a new selector     
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection     
... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed y the remote host    
... 32 more 
2016-05-11 20:01:55,600 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.datagrid-infinispan-endpoint.websocket.websocket-connector: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.datagrid-infinispan-endpoint.websocket.websocket-connector: GENDPT10004: Failed to start WebSocketServer
caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to create a child event loop   ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logs contain `Unable to establish loopback connection` which suggests that there is something wrong with your OS configuration.

The similar issue can be found here: [Failed to initialize monitor Thread: Unable to establish loopback connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011539/failed-to-initialize-monitor-thread-unable-to-establish-loopback-connection)